# How to print a variable of type NVARCHAR(MAX) while looping over a CURSOR

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure-sql-database

I am trying to write a stored procedure which generates dynamic views for tables. For that purpose I am storing the generated View in a NVARCHAR(MAX) type variable. But due to size limitations the variable is getting truncated.

I tried a couple of work around techniques but none of them seem to work for me. I can't split the variable into chunks because I do not know what size the variable will be and I want to write a generic logic for generating views.

Here is the code snippet -

```
DECLARE CURTABLE CURSOR FOR   
SELECT A
FROM TABLE A
WHERE ID = 189      
Order By ID
OPEN curTable   
FETCH NEXT FROM curTable INTO @columnname
DECLARE @tsql NVARCHAR(MAX)
WHILE @@fetch_status=0  
BEGIN   
    IF @ViewFunctionValue IS NULL
        SET @tsql = @tsql + ' ' + quotename(@columnname,'[')  
    ELSE 
        SET @tsql=@tsql+@ViewFunctionValue  
    IF @ViewFunctionValue IS NULL
        SET @tsql = @tsql + ' AS ' + quotename(@columnname,'[')  

    SET @tsql = @tsql + ', '  + CHAR(10)  

    FETCH NEXT FROM curTable INTO @columnname
END
CLOSE curTable  
DEALLOCATE curTable

SET @tsql = LEFT(@tsql,LEN(@tsql)-3) + CHAR(10) 
SET @tsql= @tsql+' FROM ' + TABLEA

PRINT @tsql
```

Comment: [I wrote a tip about this](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3185/validate-the-contents-of-large-dynamic-sql-strings-in-sql-server/)... however in your case you could `PRINT` as you go inside the loop, the stuff you change outside the loop should be pretty simple to not have to `PRINT` in order to validate.

Comment: The problem is not the variable, it's just that print doesn't print it completely. You can use substring to print the rest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/print-transact-sql:

***Remarks***

A message string can be up to **8,000** characters long if it is a non-Unicode string, and **4,000** characters long if it is a Unicode string. Longer strings are truncated. *The varchar(max) and nvarchar(max) data types are truncated to data types that are no larger than varchar(8000) and nvarchar(4000).*

This being the case you'll want to perform mulltiple Print actions, each one dealing with the next valid Chunk size, depending on if your're dealing with Standard or Unicode data types.

e.g. something like this untested code:

```
Set @p = 1
Print SubStr(@tsql, @p, 4000);
While @p < Len(@tSql)
Begin
    Set @p = @p + 4000;
    If @p < Len(@tSql)
        Print SubStr(@tsql, @p, 4000);
End
```

Answer (score 0):

I resolved my issue by printing in chunks.

There's a catch here. `PRINT` command in SQL Server prints a newline character at the end.

Since the code aimed to form a dynamic view for a table, I didn't want any new line characters at the wrong places. So, I parsed the code to find a comma( since my view has comma separated statements) after which I could safely put a new line character.

```
IF LEN(@tsql) > 3000
BEGIN
    SET @Count = 0 
    WHILE @Count < LEN(@tsql)
    BEGIN
        SET @pos = CHARINDEX(',',@tsql,3000)
        PRINT SUBSTRING(@tsql,@Count,@pos+1)
        SET @Count += @pos+1
    END 
END
ELSE
    PRINT @tsql
```